# Memory-efficient random selection from large 2-D numpy array avoiding certain pixels

Tags: python, numpy

The problem is as follows:

1. I have about ~1000 pixels out of 20000*2 whose positions I want to avoid by some distance (a few pixels, say, away from each of those positions).
2. I want to randomly select ~100,000 of the remaining pixels without replacement and record their positions (which I am finding is the difficult part).

At the moment I:

A. Create a mask from the 1000 positions.

B. Make a list of tuples containing the unmasked positions.

C. Draw from a flattened integer list describing that list of tuples. Hey presto!

But the memory requirements for B are huge and the limiting factor. I am less concerning about speed.

This is the same as [memory efficient random number iterator without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726540/memory-efficient-random-number-iterator-without-replacement) but with masked circles (swiss cheese). I wonder if it's best just to keep sampling without replacement until the 100,000 are obtained.

Thanks!

Comment: Ummm... what does the mask change for you when it comes to the memory? Or maybe give a precise question. You can try to draw a number, and check it against the mask in `O(M)` trivially or `O(ln(M))` less trivially, where `M` is `size(mask)`. You don't need need a copy of whole table with out some elements. If you fail, you retry, or find a closest point, or whatever.

Comment: How are you storing the masks?  What data structure are you using?